# Bootstrap 3: disabling carousel in modal window after closing modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a carousel within a modal window.
When a thumbnail image is clicked, a modal pops up and the corresponding carousel item is shown, firing the whole carousel.
My problem, once the modal window is closed, the carousel is still going on, cycling thru all images. If a thumbnail image is clicked again, the modal shows up but 2 images, stacked one on top of the other appears.
I understand why this is happening, I'm adding dynamically the class 'active" when a thumbnail is clicked. So the second time the carousel is fired up, two images have the 'active' class.

I would like to know if there is a way to completely deactivate the carousel.
If I try to remove the "active" class, javascript throws an error from the Bootstrap carousel function, "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined ".
I tried calling the carousel function with "interval: false" but to no avail.

Here's the code I'm using to call up the modal and carousel:

```
$("#info a").click(function(){
    var thumb = $(this).data('id'); //Get the ID of the thumbnail clicked
    //add class "active" to the corresponding carousel item
    $('#infoCarousel div[class*="item"]').each(function(i){
        if(i == thumb){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $("#carouselModal").modal('show');//Show the modal window
    //Start the carousel with the proper item
    $("#carouselModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
        $('#infoCarousel').carousel({
            number: thumb
        });
    });
});
```

And here's what I tried once the modal is closed:

```
//Once the modal window is closed, remove the "active" class from the last showing item (to prevent double image showing if carousel is fired up right away a second time)
$('#carouselModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#infoCarousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    });
    $('#infoCarousel div[class*="active"]').each(function(i){
        $(this).removeClass('active');          
    });
});
```

As mentioned, removing the class 'active' is throwing an error *(preventing normal behavior from the carousel) and calling the carousel again with "interval: false" does nothing.
You can see it in action [here](http://yveschaput.com/gdf2), just click on Info and then on a thumbnail, then close the modal and click again on  a thumbnail.
Any hints on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the `.carousel('pause')` method of the carousel?

Comment: @cvrebert That was so an obvious try I should have done. To close to the tree to see the forest, I guess. But still, no avail. I get the same error "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined". It would seem to me that I need to get the carousel completely out of the stack, like it never fired before, a complete re-initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like a good night sleep to look at a problem and find the solution.
My problem was caused by this data declaration I had left in the opening DIV of the carousel, `data-ride="carousel"` This cause the carousel to fire up at page load. Once this was taken out, my code was behaving as intended.
This is what you get when you copy/paste code and don't thoroughly review it for your specific application. And I'm guilty of that more times than I care to admit.
Hopefully this will help other "copy/pasters" to carefully review the code they paste into their applications.
Cheers!